# How to have a rails admin and only 1 admin that can edit & create new posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, authorization, pundit

I am trying to create a simple page where any visitor can read the weekly posts. I want there to only be 1 admin that can edit or create new posts.

How would I go about creating this?

I started with devise but theoretically anyone can go to the new_user_registration path and create a new user that would have access to the edit & new actions. How would I be able to restrict any new accounts from being created after the one I create? Or ideally limit the actions that any user that is not an admin can use?

I looked into Pundit for authorization but it seems like it is too much for such a simple task, is there a more simple way to do this with Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have 1 user, a single administrator, with a login and password, and no other user accounts, then I would recommend HTTP Digest Auth, which is supported by rails out-of-the-box and doesn't require any extra gems or plugins. (Or HTTP Basic Auth, but digest auth is a little more secure.)

Most of the following is taken from the [action controller guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-digest-authentication) on the rails website.

In config/routes.rb:

```
resources :posts
```

In controllers/posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
USERS = { "admin" => "password" }

before_action :authenticate, except: [:index, :show]

# actions here (index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy) 

private
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest do |username|
      USERS[username]
    end
  end
end
```

If you want, you can modify the routes so that the new/create/edit/update/destroy actions are in the 'admin/' part of the website:

In config/routes.rb:

```
scope '/admin' do
  resources :posts, except: [:index, :show]
end
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show]
```

This will still direct all post-related requests to the PostsController.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand this. Would I have to create the admin account & password in my console. Otherwise how would the authenticate method fetch the password to authenticate?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, but `authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest` takes a block; that block is given the username as the first argument, and must return the password.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can add a new attribute to your User model that define if the instantiated user is an admin or not, for example. Let's call this attribute *isAdmin*
An in your edit controller you can do the following:

```
if user.isAdmin==true
# your edition code here
else
#redirect
end
```

Comment: Hmmm so add an admin column to the user model & then I would have to add the Admin property to the specific user via my console is this correct?

Comment: Yes, using the console would be an option.

Comment: Oh that's a good question. You can for example make users ask for being admin using another dedicated controller (and views) and if you accept, isAdmin variable will be set to true.